# Eclipse Plugin: Highlight Code Line (textmarker while debugging)

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

Please do not confuse this with 'selecting code' like selecting code with a mouse.

When my debug device hits a break point I want to highlight the specific line of code.
I am using the CDT Plugin.

I already got the `lineNumber` and all I want to do now is to tell

```
editor.highlightLine(lineNumber);
```

to get something like this:

[image]

I already tried this:

```
      marker = resource.createMarker(IMarker.TEXT);
      marker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, 10);
      marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, 0);
      marker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, 10);
```

but it didn't work.

Since there are already predefined annotations provided by Eclipse and/or the CDT Plugin I'd like to reuse them. But how to access and use them inside sourcecode?

[image]

Comment: what is the editor you are using? is it default eclipse editor? means in your code editor.highlightline(lineNumber);, here "editor" is what?  eclipse default editor?

Comment: I am using the `CEditor` from the CDT plugin which extends `TextEditor`

Comment: Check for selectAndReveal(int, int) is present in CDT plugin editor? this methos is used to highlight a line in TextEditor of eclipse!!

Comment: Have you checked your colors? It might be there but invisible

Comment: @Lai How could I set the color?

Comment: @Rock123 well I tried this but this is just "text selection" like if you mark text with your mouse. So when you click somewhere the selection/the marking disappears

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own marker using an extension point `"org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"` and adding super attribute of type `"org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"`. After setting up your marker, you still need to describe its look and feel by adding the annotation extension point `"org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes"`

I am not exactly sure of your intentions but this link might help http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-eclipse-plugin-guide/section3.html

Comment: Well.. this does not make sense to me. What is the CDT Plugin good for if I have to reinvent the wheel after all? I mean .. all this is here that one can visualize the debugging process more easily.. how can it be that such a basic thing like highlighting a single line demands so much effort?

Answer (score 0):

Marker is the thing on your ruler. You need to look at the editor background painting. Take a look at [InstructionPointerManager.java](https://github.com/eclipse/cdt/blob/d55bca53a5b12ffce1aa9574754cdd6704d1d351/dsf/org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui/src/org/eclipse/cdt/dsf/debug/ui/sourcelookup/InstructionPointerManager.java)

Comment: I see that this class is `internal`. I assume I have to write my own `InstructionPointerManager`? This looks quite helpful. I will not forget to mark your answer if it works.

Comment: But you're sure that there is no easier way to do this even though I am using the CDT Plugin already with my Eclipse Application? This plugin should alreads support this behaviour..

Comment: I am not sure if there is no other simpler way. CDT has 2 debug frameworks (CDI and DSF) and this class is a part of DSF. My understanding is that whenever you write your debugger you need to implement something like this.

Comment: Here http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.cdt.devel/16070 it says, that the DSF approach shall be used. But I got a few things running with this approach http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Debugger/how-to.html It seems like that there is no uniform way for this. Maybe I'm wrong but I think the community should take a few steps back and reconsider their design at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And I solve it by creating my own marker. I follow the step of this blog http://cubussapiens.hu/2011/05/custom-markers-and-annotations-the-bright-side-of-eclipse/ and create a marker when the lineNumber changed. It will highlight this line.